# Почему мой код не работает

Tags: python, классы

```
shop_search = input('enter the shop: ')

def ps():
    product_search = input('enter the product: ')

class Shop:
    def set(self, name, department, price):
        self.name = name
        self.department = department
        self.price = price

milk = Shop()
milk.name = 'milk'
milk.department = 'dairy products'
milk.price = '1,5$'

def d():
    print(f'name : {milk.name}, department: {milk.department}, price: {milk.price}')

def ss():
    if shop_search == 'perekrestok':
        print(ps())
        if ps() == 'milk':
            print(d())
    else:

        print('the name isn"t correct')

ss()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
shop_search = input('enter the shop: ')

def ps():
    product_search = input('enter the product: ')
    return product_search                              # +++

class Shop:
    def set(self, name, department, price):
        self.name = name
        self.department = department
        self.price = price

milk = Shop()
milk.name = 'milk'
milk.department = 'dairy products'
milk.price = '1,5$'

def d():
    print(f'name : {milk.name}, department: {milk.department}, price: {milk.price}')

def ss():
    if shop_search == 'perekrestok':
        _ps = ps()                                     # +++
        print(_ps)
        if _ps == 'milk':
            print(d())
    else:
        print('the name isn"t correct')

ss()
```

---

```
enter the shop: perekrestok
enter the product: milk
milk
name : milk, department: dairy products, price: 1,5$
```